# file_put_contents return URL after execution

Tags: php

I have a set of functions like this:

```
<?php
//Get the base-64 string from data
$filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);

//Decode the string
$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

//Save the image
file_put_contents('img.png', $unencodedData);
?>
```

This saves a file called `img.png` to the server. Now I need the last `file_put_contents` function to return the path/absolute URL of the file it just created. I can't seem to find an option for this in the php documentation.

Is there an option for this or alternatively any other method for returning the path/absolute URL?

Thanks

Comment: The file might not have a URL, if you didn't write into a directory under the web root.

Comment: Okay lets, say I set the file to be written to /var/www in the server, how do I 'return' this path/URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
      $abs_path = __DIR__.'/img.png';
      file_put_contents($abs_path, $unencodedData);
      echo $abs_path;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you please tell me what does the '__DIR__.' stand for? I couldn't find anything about it on google

Comment: __DIR__ is php defined constant. that tell you absolute path of current file directory

Comment: Is it possible to return the URL of the file like this? `http://localhost/img.png`, rather than `Library/WebServer/Documents/img.png`

Comment: Actually I found out, '$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']' gives me the correct URL path

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing into the same folder as the script, as in your example:

```
dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/' . 'img.png'
```